# customizing the delete view in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-admin

Here is the `rails_admin` view for delete. I want to customize it: for example i would like to show firstly the posts of this user before completely deleting the record.

I am using [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) gem

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you added the code for the view and the controller.

But basically, if you want to display the posts of the user in the **admin** view, you should first create a variable for this user in the admin controller, then display the posts in the view using a block.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and customize your own delete page by copying this file from their gem. https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/activo/app/views/rails_admin/main/_delete_notice.html.haml
Create it on the same directory as your project. `your_app/app/views/rails_admin/main/_delete_notice.html.haml` and edit it on your own liking.